# What is the English title of Tolstoy's memoirs "Without love, It's easier to live"?

Tags: identification-request, russian-language, leo-tolstoy

I am trying to find the English name of the memoirs by Leo Tostoy titled [Without love, It's easier to live](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28479288) (original Russian title *Без любви жить легче*).

I could not find any mention of it neither in English, nor in Russian Wikipedia.

Was this memoir ever translated into English? If yes, what is it English title?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Do you have any other details, e.g. year of first publication and whether it was an original publication by Tolstoy rather than a volume that later editors created? The reason is that I can't find it on the [Russian Wikipedia page Библиография Льва Толстого](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE). (I naively searched "Без любви жить легче" and substrings of that title, since I don't know Russian.)

Comment: This may be a compilation. On [Litres](https://www.litres.ru/lev-tolstoy/bez-lubvi-zhit-legche/), for example, I see the year 2014 as the year of publication. According to [this site](https://www.livelib.ru/book/1000975186-bez-lyubvi-zhit-legche-sbornik-lev-tolstoj), this compilation contains [A Confession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Confession) as well as several other works, including excerpts from diaries.

Comment: That may explain why there is no English translation, since the individual works may already have been translated. If you can track down the English translations for the works contained or excerpted in that volume, you could use your comment and these other findings to write up an answer to your own question. This may then also be helpful to other visitors of this site.